# Enviar e-mail com PHPMailer e Cron (Ubuntu)

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, cron

Para agendar envios de e-mail, é preciso fazer algo além de colocar o arquivo dentro da pasta /etc/cron.daily (para envios diários)? Esse código funciona quando eu executo direto no servidor, é preciso editar algum outro arquivo para fazer o envio agendado?

```
<?php
    require 'http://insidetv.net.br/PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php';

    $email = new PHPMailer();

    $email -> IsSMTP();
    $email -> Mailer = 'smtp';
    $email -> SMTPAuth = true;
    $email -> Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $email -> Port = 465;
    $email -> SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
    $email -> CharSet = 'UTF-8';

    $email -> Username = "insidetvoficial@gmail.com";
    $email -> Password = "********";

    $email -> IsHTML(true);
    $email -> SingleTo = true;

    $email -> From = "insidetvoficial@gmail.com";
    $email -> FromName = "InsideTv";

    $email -> addAddress("email@hotmail.com");

    $email -> Subject = "teste";
    $email -> Body = "teste";
    $email -> send();
?>
```

Comment: Certeza que é isto mesmo? `require 'http://insidetv.net.br/PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php';`

Comment: Sim, o caminho está correto.

Comment: Não sei como estão seus arquivos, mas tente `require 'PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php';`.

Comment: Continua sem enviar.

Comment: Pode postar o comando que utilizou para agendar esta tarefa?

Comment: Pelo que eu li, para agendar hora, dia, semana, mês, é só colocar o arquivo para dentro da respectiva pasta. Só é necessário executar um comando para horários específicos.